# Server's Data is not getting received by Client in Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to create a function that allows the client to download a file from the server.  Below oare the relevant portions of the code.  I have gotten to the point where a text file with the same name is created in the client folder, but it is just empty with no data.  The programs get to the "received file line" but nothin else.

Client Code:

```
       elif cmd == "DOWN":
            filename = data[1]
            print(filename)
            client.send(filename.encode(FORMAT))
            f = open("client/" + filename, 'wb')
            while True:
                print("receiving data")
                data = client.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT)
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)
                print("Data: %s", (data))
            f.close()
```

Server Code:

```
       elif cmd == "DOWN":
            file = conn.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT)
            f = open("server/"+file, 'rb')
            l = f.read(1024)

            while (l):
                conn.send(l.encode(FORMAT))
                print("send data", repr(1))
                l = f.read(1024)
            f.close()
            print("done sending")
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the server
> DOWN abc.txt
abc.txt
recieving data
```

The program enters the loop to receive the data, but nothing else. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What is printed at the server? At the server, did you print the filename, is it opened successfully?

Comment: The server shows absolutely nothing

Comment: So it doesn’t even get the filename? You need to make your code a small [mre] which can be run by anyone _without adding anything__.